# Call Block_Release inside block to be released

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

Is it possible to release a block inside itself? For the compiler it's fine, but I'm not sure if at runtime it will crash, since it releases memory that is executed at the same time.

```
cancel_block_t someFunction(/*args*/){
    __block BOOL canceled = NO;
    __block cancel_block_t cancel_block = Block_copy(^{
        canceled = YES;
        Block_Release(cancel_block); //<-- can I do this?
        cancel_block = NULL; //<-- can I do this?
    });
    // […]
    return cancel_block;
}
```

Would this approach be more safe?

```
 cancel_block_t someFunction(/*args*/){
    __block BOOL canceled = NO;
    __block cancel_block_t cancel_block = Block_copy(^{
        canceled = YES;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.001 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),^{
            Block_Release(cancel_block);
            cancel_block = NULL;
        });
    });
    // […]
    return cancel_block;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Edit #1: corrected return type of function.

Comment: "I'm not sure if at runtime it will crash" ... maybe let us know what happens at run time.

Comment: [Microsoft based... but still very relevant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/05/10463645.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this non-ARC code? ARC will automatically copy, retain, and release blocks.

Anyway, this is not safe, at least not always. I've seen crashes for similar behavior. The issue is that the reference to the `__block` variable is within the same block object that `Block_release()` may deallocate. So, trying to set the variable can access memory after it's been freed (and maybe reused).

About your function:

1) Why does it return a pointer to a block type? It would be more normal for the function to just return the block type (which is already a reference). That is, `someFunction()` should have a return type of `cancel_block_t`, not `cancel_block_t*`. Anyway, it's not safe to take the address of a `__block` variable, since such a variable can change location. It starts life on the stack but gets moved to the heap.

2) The normal semantics for a function that returns a block would be to return an autoreleased object. So, `someFunction()` should just `return [cancel_block autorelease];` (given that it's already been copied). The caller is responsible for retaining it if it wants to keep it beyond the current scope or autorelease pool. If it's submitted to a function (e.g. `dispatch_async()`), then that function is responsible for retaining it. In other words, the memory management semantics are the same as any other object. The block should not try to release itself.

Comment: It's non-ARC code. to 1) was a mistake of me, allready corrected in my code just to return cancel_block_t. to 2) can I `return [cancel_block autorelease];` with no autorelease pool around? Or at least I'm not sure if there is one. (Since I'm hooking into another process)

Comment: Well, it's hard to know about the autorelease thing without knowing more about the exact context in which you code will be called. That said, lots of stuff in Cocoa just assumes there's an autorelease pool, so you're going to be pretty limited if you can't assume that. Is `someFunction()` called by your code or by the host app? You can always establish an autorelease pool in your own code. Alternatively, you can make `someFunction()` return a +1 reference to the block and make the caller release it. In that case, you should name it with "create" in the name, per convention.

Comment: Its called inside the hooked function also by my code. So it would be safe to create an autorelease pool even if one exists!?

Comment: Decided to use a static variable to store the block into (so its not in any autorelease pool and I have full control), named the function `create_and_run_cancelable_dispatch_after_block` and properly released the block and set it to `NULL` . Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you can nest autorelease pools. You can just do `@autoreleasepool { ... }` around some code. A static variable doesn't seem safe if `create_and_run_cancelable_dispatch_after_block()` can be called multiple times. (Also, if you name your function with "create" then it should, by convention, return a +1 reference. That is, the callers have an obligation to release what they receive.)

Comment: I assign the result (a +1 reference) of `create_and_run_cancelable_dispatch_after_block()` to `static cancel_block_t cancelBlockRef` only if `cancelBlockRef` is `nil`. Then i do my work and afterwards `[cancelBlockRef release]; cancelBlockRef = nil;`. So inside the function it's just a normal variable that I assign as above.